# PHP progress where the end is unknown

Tags: php, math, optimization

I need to show some progress in an application where the end time is unknown. The user must know the process is still running. I've took an approach where I take always a percentage of the step to never reach 100 percent. My code does work but I want to optimize it. Is there a way to replace the inner for loop with a mathematical function?

```
$start = new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime('2999-01-01');

$total = $end->format('U') - $start->format('U');
while (true) {
    $secondsLeft = $end->format('U') - $start->format('U');

    $progress = 0;
    $amount = 100;
    $worked = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total - $secondsLeft; $i ++) {
        $worked = $amount / 100;
        $amount = $amount - $worked;
        $progress += $worked;
    }
    print('worked: ' . $worked . '  ');
    print('progress: ' . $progress . PHP_EOL);

    $start->modify('+1 seconds');
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

similiar effect, it's never reach 100%

```
$worked = 0;
$x = 100;
$z = 0;
while (true) {
    $y = $z; 
    $worked++;
    $z = $worked/($x+$worked); 
    echo $z-$y.";".$z."\n";    
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was hoping more for a way to avoid the for loop. But it looks likle nobody has a mathematical solution.